# How I can run command in python script as a root?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, tcp, nmap

I have a python script to do the TCP scanning. I am using the python3_nmap library so the command is as below:

```
import nmap3
nmap.nmap_syn_scan(self.ip ,"-p 443 -v -T4")
```

Every time I need to enter my password, how can I change the code to not asking me for a password?

- I do not need to change the privilege of whole python script because I am just calling a function inside it in a robot framework, so I should somehow ignore entering a password for that especial subprocess!

Comment: do you run your Python script with `sudo`?

Comment: @JanWilamowski No. somehow I need to do it in the script because I am going to run this script in a robot framework. I do not want to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need some automation here. [Pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) is a good choice.
You have to run your python script with appropriate privileges. Giving the permission for execution could be automated like this:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('sudo python <path_to_your_python_script>')  # make sure about environment
child.expect('password')  # wait to read password string in terminal
child.sendline('<your_password_here>')  # enter user password
```

Comment: Actually, I do not need to run the whole python script, I will call a function inside it, and that function is doing some subprocesses that need to enter a password like a TCP scanning.

Comment: You mean, there is a module for scanning and you want to import and call some specific routines from that module in your script as a root. Am I right?  How is your script is invoked?

Comment: Ok. I have a python script with different methods inside it, one of them is doing tcp scanning using a function from nmap3 library which needs root privilege, in another side, I have a robot file which is calling this method. so when I run the robot file it asks to enter a password because of that tcp scanning.